# jQuery checbox problems add checkbox selected to total

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hi all i have a little problem with a checkbox.

First of all i have 7 checkbox

Php:

```
  <span class="mobile-only">Cantitate:</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="extra_ids[]" value="1" />
            <input type="checkbox" class="add" data-amount="100" name="extra_units[1]" id="extra_units_1" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="col1 extra-name" style="font-size: 18px;">
            GPS                <span class="mobile-only">Total:</span>
            <span title="100" style="cursor:pointer">
               <b> 10 EURO / Zi </B>
            </span>
        </div>
     </div>
        <div class="extra">
        <div class="col5 extra-select">
            <span class="mobile-only">Cantitate:</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="extra_ids[]" value="6" />
            <input type="checkbox" class="add" data-amount="40" name="extra_units[6]" id="extra_units_6" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="col1 extra-name" style="font-size: 18px;">
            Internet WiFi in masina                <span class="mobile-only">Total:</span>
            <span title="40" style="cursor:pointer">
               <b> 4 EURO / Zi </B>
            </span>
        </div>
     </div>
        <div class="extra">
        <div class="col5 extra-select">
            <span class="mobile-only">Cantitate:</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="extra_ids[]" value="8" />
            <input type="checkbox" class="add" data-amount="10" name="extra_units[8]" id="extra_units_8" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="col1 extra-name" style="font-size: 18px;">
            Pre-Pay Spălare Auto                <span class="mobile-only">Total:</span>
            <span title="10" style="cursor:pointer">
               <b> 1 EURO / Zi </B>
            </span>
        </div>
     </div>
        <div class="extra">
        <div class="col5 extra-select">
            <span class="mobile-only">Cantitate:</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="extra_ids[]" value="4" />
            <input type="checkbox" class="add" data-amount="50" name="extra_units[4]" id="extra_units_4" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="col1 extra-name" style="font-size: 18px;">
            Scaun copil                <span class="mobile-only">Total:</span>
            <span title="50" style="cursor:pointer">
               <b> 5 EURO / Zi </B>
            </span>
        </div>
     </div>
        <div class="extra">
        <div class="col5 extra-select">
            <span class="mobile-only">Cantitate:</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="extra_ids[]" value="5" />
            <input type="checkbox" class="add" data-amount="200" name="extra_units[5]" id="extra_units_5" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="col1 extra-name" style="font-size: 18px;">
            Sofer adiţional                <span class="mobile-only">Total:</span>
            <span title="200" style="cursor:pointer">
               <b> 20 EURO / Zi </B>
            </span>
        </div>
     </div>
        <div class="extra">
        <div class="col5 extra-select">
            <span class="mobile-only">Cantitate:</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="extra_ids[]" value="7" />
            <input type="checkbox" class="add" data-amount="20" name="extra_units[7]" id="extra_units_7" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="col1 extra-name" style="font-size: 18px;">
            Tableta PC Touchscreen                <span class="mobile-only">Total:</span>
            <span title="20" style="cursor:pointer">
               <b> 2 EURO / Zi </B>
            </span>
        </div>
     </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.add').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) + parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
    } else {
     $('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) - parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
    }
});
```

I wan't to add a hidden checkbox with a value (specified by me) and the sum of the selected items added to the existing value. (the value specified by me)

Can someone help me ?

Comment: what to you mean by hidden checkbox it is either checkbox or hidden in html

Comment: the hidden checkbox must be already checked, and hidden and the sum of the checkboxes to start from his value

Comment: Now the sum is starting from 0, and i want to start from the specified value

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. The hidden can not be checked. Can you try to explain it otherwise?

Comment: Ok, each checkbox has a value ok ?  data-amount="100"

Comment: on click the values are added to a total...

Comment: 100+100+100 = 300, something like that.

Comment: the total sum of 300, i wanna be added to an existing value something like  <input type="checkbox" class="add" data-amount="500" checked> <br>  and the sum start from this already checked checkbox.

Comment: see here : http://imgur.com/a/DEjlY  and on click i wanna http://imgur.com/a/mg692

Comment: The total must be another hidden checkbox that is already checked and all others should be put on that total

Answer (score 0):

You can have a checkbox which is hidden with the initial value set to the amount you want.

```
<div style="visibility: hidden;"> <input type="checkbox" class="add" data-amount="100" name="total" id="total" value="100" /> </div>
```

And then script would be:

```
    <script>
    $('.add').click(function() {
        var total = parseInt($('#total').val());
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
         //$('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) + parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
         $('#total').val(total + parseInt($(this).data('amount') ) ) ;
        } else {
         //$('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) - parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
         $('#total').val(total - parseInt($(this).data('amount') ) ) ;
        }            
        console.log("total = " + $('#total').val() );

    });
    </script>
```